# Element-wise summing of arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider this set of docs:

```
[
  {_id:1, values:[1, 2, 3]},
  {_id:2, values:[4, 5, 6]}
]
```

Is there any elegant way to group/sum the arrays into a new array, where the nth element is the sum of the nth elements of the original documents?

```
{_id:null, values:[5, 7, 9]}
```

I can sum up specific elements in an aggregation step:

```
{$group:{
    _id:null,
    Values0: {$sum:{$arrayElemAt:["$values",0]}},
    Values1: {$sum:{$arrayElemAt:["$values",1]}},
    Values2: {$sum:{$arrayElemAt:["$values",2]}}
}},
```

But I can't get these back into an array. Also something that would require less typing would be highly appreciated :). If this doesn't work I can loop over the bson docs in C# and construct the answer that way but would prefer something in an aggregation pipeline (or mapreduce maybe? Haven't looked into that yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to get an array of arrays and then use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to process that array. Using [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) you can generate indexes that can be used to get each item of both arrays (result and currently processed item). Value at index zero will be an `initialValue` for `$reduce` and values at indexes `1...size` will be added to the result in every iteration.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            values : {
                $push: "$values"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $slice: [ "$values", 1, { $size: "$values" } ] },
                    initialValue: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 0 ] },
                    in: {
                        $map: {
                            input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$$this" } ] },
                            as: "index",
                            in: {
                                $add: [
                                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this", "$$index" ]  },
                                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$value", "$$index" ]  }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qrGYT8_CaqR)

Comment: That worked, thx! Will have to chew on it for a while to get it all.